# How can I transpose array of hashes in ruby

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a following array of hashes as the input :-

```
input =[
{"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"123"}, 
{"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field B", "Value"=>"333"}, 
{"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field C", "Value"=>"555"}, 
{"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"789"}, 
{"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field B", "Value"=>"999"},
{"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field D", "Value"=>"444"}
]
```

I would like to transform this array of hash as below

```
output =[
{"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C" => "555", "Field D" => ""}, 
{"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field C" => "", "Field D" => "444"}
]
```

I can fetch unique ID and keys as below

```
irb(main):099:0> unique_id = input.map { |p| p["ID"] }.uniq
=> ["100", "200"]
irb(main):100:0> unique_keys = input.map { |p| p["Key"] }.uniq
=> ["Field A", "Field B", "Field C", "Field D"]
```

However, I am not able to proceed beyond this to create unique array of hashes for each ID containing keys/value pairs as defined on the input hash.

Comment: I added all keys in my answer, check edited answer.

Comment: The desired structure isn't as useful as it should be. An array of hashes, where the "ID" is unique in each hash, could be better stored as a single hash. This question actually looks like an XY problem where you're asking how to do "Y"  but really should ask about "X". "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might do the job:

```
keys = input.map { |hash| hash['Key'] }.uniq
result = Hash.new { |result, id| result[id] = {} }
input.each { |hash| result[hash['ID']].merge!(hash['Key'] => hash['Value']) }
result.default = nil # optional: remove the default value

result.each do |id, hash| 
  (keys - hash.keys).each { |key| hash[key] = '' }
  hash['ID'] = id
end    

result.values
#=> [{"Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C"=>"555", "Field D"=>"", "ID"=>"100"},
#    {"Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field D"=>"444", "Field C"=>"", "ID"=>"200"}]
```

If you're certain values are never falsy you can replace:

```
(keys - hash.keys).each { |key| hash[key] = '' }
# with
keys.each { |key| hash[key] ||= '' }
```

I first create a hash `result` to save the resulting hashes, I set the value to defaults to a new hash. Then I get the correct hash based upon *ID* and merge the key-value pairs into the hash. Lastly I add the missing keys to the hashes and set their values to an empty string and add the *ID* under which the hash is saved to the hash.

> **note:** If your `input` array contains duplicate key-value pairs, the last one will be used. For example, say both `{"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"123"}` and `{"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"456"}` are present. Then `"Field A" => "456"` will be set, since it's the latter of the two.

Comment: `result[hash['ID']].merge!(hash['Key'] => hash['Value'])` can be replaced with `result[hash['ID']][hash['Key']] = hash['Value']`, however I find the first one better readable.

Comment: thanks, it nearly works for me.

However, I would also like to see so that keys in all hashes to be same as well.

  blank "Field D" => "" for ID = 100
  blank "Field C" => "" for ID = 200

Comment: Brilliant !! It works..

This was my first question on StackOverflow. Glad to know there is such as brilliant tech community around.

Comment: @SKools My solution doesn't return the key-value pairs in the exact order you want, however most of the time you don't care about the order of an hash. If you for some reason do, the [answer of ray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089908/3982562) also returns the correct order. However his answer uses too many acronyms in my opinion, although I largely agree with his chosen solution.

Comment: Nice solution. No need for **update:** (ever). Just edit as though you were editing a draft of an article you had written. It flows better that way. It would also be easier to read if you avoid the need on the part of the reader to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 3):

Try Following,

```
fields = input.map {|x| x['Key'] }.uniq

output = input.group_by  { |x| x['ID'] }
     .map { |k,v| ([['ID', k]] + v.map {|z| z.values_at('Key','Value') }).to_h }

output.map! { |x| {'ID' => x['ID']}.merge fields.to_h {|z| [z, x[z].to_s]} }
```

Output will be,

```
[
  {"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C"=>"555", "Field D"=>""}, 
  {"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field C"=>"", "Field D"=>"444"}
]
```

Comment: @SebastianPalma Yes thanks, added in edit but order of keys are not as prescribed due to methodology I used!

Comment: `v.map {|z| [z['Key'], z['Value']]}` could be replaced with `v.map {|z| z.values_at('Key', 'Value') }` which I personally find more readable. And `fields.map {|z| [z, x[z].to_s]}.to_h` could be replaced with `fields.to_h {|z| [z, x[z].to_s]}`

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thanks, I missed it in pursue of output :P edited answer!

Comment: Nice one. `x[z].to_s` is cute but only works if the values are strings. That's true in the example but there's no reason to limit the generality. Better: `x[z] || ""`. Best (imo, oc): `x.key?(z) ? x[z] : ""`, which I think reads better and also allows intended `nil` values in `input`.

Answer (score 1):

My answer has three steps.

*Step 1: Obtain the unique values of `"ID"` and the unique keys of the form `"Field X"`*

```
ids, keys = input.map { |h| h.values_at("ID", "Key") }.transpose.map(&:uniq)
  #=> [["100", "200"], ["Field A", "Field B", "Field C", "Field D"]]
```

See [Hash#values_at](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at). The calculations are as follows:

```
a = input.map { |h| h.values_at("ID", "Key") }
  #=> [["100", "Field A"], ["100", "Field B"], ["100", "Field C"],
  #    ["200", "Field A"], ["200", "Field B"], ["200", "Field D"]] 
b = a.transpose
  #=> [["100", "100", "100", "200", "200", "200"],
  #    ["Field A", "Field B", "Field C", "Field A", "Field B", "Field D"]] 
ids, keys = b.map(&:uniq)
  #=> [["100", "200"], ["Field A", "Field B", "Field C", "Field D"]] 
ids
  #=> ["100", "200"] 
keys
  #=> ["Field A", "Field B", "Field C", "Field D"]
```

*Step 2: Construct a hash whose keys are the unique values of `"ID"` and whose values are hashes to be completed and extracted in Step 3*

```
h = ids.each_with_object({}) { |id,h|
  h[id] = keys.each_with_object("ID"=>id) { |key,g| g[key] = "" } }
  #=> {"100"=>{"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"", "Field B"=>"", "Field C"=>"",
  #            "Field D"=>""},
  #    "200"=>{"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"", "Field B"=>"", "Field C"=>"",
  #            "Field D"=>""}}
```

*Step 3: Loop through `input` to complete the values of the hash constructed in Step 2, then, as a final step, extract the values from that hash*

```
input.each_with_object(h) { |g,h| h[g["ID"]].update(g["Key"]=>g["Value"]) }.values
  #=> [{"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C"=>"555",
  #     "Field D"=>""},
  #    {"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field C"=>"",
  #     "Field D"=>"444"}]
```

See [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) and [Hash#values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-values). The two calculations are as follows:

```
h = input.each_with_object(h) { |g,h| h[g["ID"]].update(g["Key"]=>g["Value"]) }
  #=> {"100"=>{"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333","Field C"=>"555",
  #            "Field D"=>""},
  #    "200"=>{"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999","Field C"=>"",
  #            "Field D"=>"444"}} 
h.values
  #=> <as above>
```

Answer (score 0):

The output structure isn't what I'd ever want to work with, and it looks like the input structure is influencing the desired output. That results in an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Hashes are extremely efficient, especially when you have something that acts like an index field in a database. Iterating over an array to find a value is extremely inefficient in comparison to a hash, so I'd recommend taking a second look at those two structures.

Converting the input to a true hash isn't hard:

```
input = [
  {"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"123"},  
  {"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field B", "Value"=>"333"},  
  {"ID"=>"100", "Key"=>"Field C", "Value"=>"555"},  
  {"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field A", "Value"=>"789"},  
  {"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field B", "Value"=>"999"},  
  {"ID"=>"200", "Key"=>"Field D", "Value"=>"444"}   
]                                                   

output = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = {} }  # => {}
input.each { |e|      
  id = e['ID']        
  key = e['Key']      
  value = e['Value']  

  output[id][key] = value 
}
```

Which results in:

```
output
# => {"100"=>{"Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C"=>"555"},
#     "200"=>{"Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field D"=>"444"}}
```

The benefit of this is pretty obvious, if you want the data for `"200"` it's easy to grab:

```
output['200'] # => {"Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field D"=>"444"}
output['200']['Field B'] # => "999"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
keys = input.map { |hash| hash['Key'] }.uniq

output = input.group_by  { |x| x['ID'] }.map { |k,v| ([['ID', k]] + v.map {|z| z.values_at('Key','Value') }).to_h }

output.map! { |x| {'ID' => x['ID']}.merge fields.map {|z| [z, x[z].to_s]}.to_h }
```

The following gives me the output as shown below

```
[
 {"ID"=>"100", "Field A"=>"123", "Field B"=>"333", "Field C"=>"555", "Field D"=>""}, 
 {"ID"=>"200", "Field A"=>"789", "Field B"=>"999", "Field C"=>"", "Field D"=>"444"}
]
```

thanks you everyone for your input

Comment: This is simply a reposts of the [answer of ray](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089908/3982562). Where you only change `fields.to_h { ... }` to `fields.map { ... }.to_h`. If a certain answer doesn't work because you're using an older Ruby version, you can comment that under his answer, so he can update his answer accordingly. I suggest removing this answer and simply giving him the check mark, commenting that you use a Ruby version lower than 2.6.0 and that `to_h` with a block is not available.

Comment: I agree with @3limin4t0r on every point. Note also that for this code to work `keys =` must be replaced with `fields =` in the first line. If you leave your answer up it won't be long before it starts attracting downvotes...

Comment: "[Are answers which merely summarize other answers acceptable?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300586/128421)".